# VisualVM Memory sampling

Tags: visualvm, memory-profiling

I am doing some memory profiling on a java application using VisualVM. I have a large amount of char arrays and strings but what I want to do is to analyze to which objects they belong.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Take a *heap dump* from your monitored application. In the heap dump you can see individual instances of `char[]` and `String` and you can also see which objects reference them.